# Show full datalist on click/type?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, input, html-datalist

Hi guys I have a HTML5 input combined with a datalist, is there a way to show the entire list when the input box is clicked or typed in to.

For example,

An input with a datalist and options {ab,ac,bb,bc}

typing a will only show ab and ac. I would like it to still show all options.

in chrome there is a little arrow you can click to show the entire datalist, this is not the case in firefox though.

Is there a way to do this in firefox?

HTML - tried autocomplete = false, but doesn't effect the datalist

```
<input id="one" list="List">
<datalist id="List" autocomplete=false>
    <option>ab</option>
    <option>ac</option>
    <option>bb</option>
    <option>bc</option>
</datalist>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qapsjxx7/

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Longer answer: yes, but we'd like to see what you've already tried and having trouble getting working

Comment: ah sorry i had a jfiddle must not have added the edit 2 secs

Comment: By all means add a jsfiddle, but you should also have the code in the question

Comment: As per my knowledge, there's no way to list all that records, but yes if you double click on `textbox` or just press `down arrow` after a focus then it will list all items.